# SQL count on multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have two columns in my table say, `first_name` and `last_name` and I want to find out how many people share the same name for example:

```
Name Count | Name
-------------------------
 12        | John Smith
  8        | Bill Gates
  4        | Steve Jobs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by both columns - eg:

```
select firstname, lastname, count(*) as `Name Count`
from table
group by firstname, lastname
```

Comment: +1.  This is the most elegant solution. Might want to add a note that in case the collation for the firstname and/or lastname columns is case sensitive, then the OP could wrap them in a LOWER() or UPPER() function to make it case insensitive -- SELECT LOWER(firstname) AS firstname, LOWER(lastname) AS lastname, ...

Comment: @spencer7593: I think you have just added that note for me - it's also implicit in Anton's answer. Other collation issues may also be significant, such as whether accented versus unaccented characters should affect the results - this is something that the OP should be best qualified to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since names can have different capitalizations (i.e. 'John' and 'john'), and possibly excess spaces in the database, first use a subquery that cleans up and concatenates the first and last names, and then use `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `name_count`
FROM (
    SELECT CONCAT(LOWER(TRIM(`first_name`)), ' ', LOWER(TRIM(`last_name`))) AS `full_name`
    FROM `table`
) AS `table_with_concat_names`
GROUP BY `full_name`
ORDER BY `name_count` DESC;
```

You'll notice I applied `LOWER(TRIM())` to both the first and last names. This way, they are made all lowercase with LOWER() so that 'John Smith' and 'john smith' are the same person when compared, and also I used TRIM() to remove excess spaces, so 'John Smith ' (space after) and 'John Smith' are the same person too.

Comment: I believe that cleaning the data is not a job for the queries. If data is dirty, it should stay as such. Also, GROUP BY can be case insensitive (it can be specified via the collation), which makes the usage of LOWER() superflous.

Comment: @Diego Great point about the GROUP BY. I didn't know what settings the asker had so I was going for the catch-all solution.

Comment: @Diego As far as cleaning goes, I have to disagree. In a regular application, you're right, but this sounds like an ad-hoc one-time query for the user, so it's just easy to run in SQL and let the sanitization happen on-the-fly in the query. Keeping the data dirty means having to perform such standardization in PHP later, which will make things more complicated for the asker (I'm pretty sure they're still a beginner).

Comment: I still believe that data should be taken as-is, and cleaned during input (if ever). Cleaning it on the fly would mean repeating the same operation over and over. It starts with a TRIM(), it ends in a complicated REGEX() to deal with "J ohn", "Jhon", "jjohn", "Johnn", "Jon" and so on. **Especially** because OP seems to be a beginner, it's important that he/she learns to properly sanitise data before saving it to the database.

Comment: Yes but it sounds like the data already exists. I do agree that new ta should be sanitized during input.

Comment: I know that data already exist. By providing a solution that does not clean it, I'm expecting next question to be "how can I group dirty data?", which would bring it closer to a proper sanitisation. One step at a time. :)

Comment: It's not necessary to concatenate the two columns (firstname and lastname), they can be handled separately.

Comment: @spencer7593 You're right. I make the assumption that the asker would like to compare full names because that's what they have in their example.

Comment: @Diego Nothing wrong with your approach. I like to guide the asker to that type of question via example because in my experience they don't always come up with it on their own.

Answer (score 0):

Use a group by clause

```
select (firstname + ' ' + lastname) as Name, count(*) as 'Name Count'
from table
group by (firstname + lastname)
```

Comment: In MySQL, the `+` operator does not perform string concatenation, it  performs numeric addition. For values of firstname and lastname that do not begin with a digit (as the first non-space character), the expression is going to return a 0. It's very likely this query will return one row, and not be the resultset the OP specified.